# How to execute custom Alfresco script on saving document opened via WebDAV or CIFS?

Tags: webdav, alfresco, cifs

I want to open an Excel file to edit offline via WebDAV or CIFS and run my script at the Alfresco side to parse the content of the file when user saves a workbook.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [content rule](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Client_Manage_Content_Rules) for inbound/updated documents. This way, regardless of which interface the user leverages to access documents (HTTP/WebDAV/CIFS/FTP) the rule will be triggered, and you can set it to "Execute Script" as an outcome.

Comment: As I see there isn't any condition for updated documents. But all that conditions are for inbound or updated documents. So I can write my own rule and execute it. Am I right?

Comment: I don't really get your comment, but you have conditions for both updated and incoming documents. Then, technically you don't write rules, you configure them. What you write is the script you're going to execute as part of the rule.

Comment: Well. I need to write an action and configure existing rules. Right?

Comment: The "Execute Script" action is already available, if you can just write a Javascript for your purposes then you only have to configure the rule. If Javascript is not enough or not what you wanted, then you need also to develop a Java Action.

Comment: If you are dealing with text content javascript is the easiest way to go. This is how you access the content as string: var content = document.properties.content.content;

You might also want to use the Javascript Console to develop your script: http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/JavascriptConsole (disclaimer: I have written it)

Comment: @Florian awesome tool, I love it!